# Flutter: I can't get document from a firestore collection... why?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I really cannot understand this one... Please help!

I have this great app which scan a QR code and return a string (`barcode`). Now I would like to use that string as an input to make a firestore enquery. This is my code

```
Future barcodeScanning() async {
      try {
        String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
        getData(barcode);
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() => barcodeFinal = 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    }

void getData(String zz) {

      DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('books').document(zz);
      documentReference.get().then((datasnapshot) {
        if (datasnapshot.exists) {
          print(datasnapshot.data['name'].toString());
        } else {
          print("No such book");
        }
      });
```

This does not work and I end of in "No such book" always all the time even if the document exists in the firestore collection. Interestingly if I write `getData('theNameOfTheDocument');` then it works. I believe there must something wrong with async and handling future value but I can figure out...

This is the database structure
[image]

Comment: Please attach screenshot for Database structure, as you might need to run "where()" query to get info. Thanks

Comment: Ok I will do that but I am trying to get a document only and I know the documentID. I am not querying the collection. I just want to get a document

Comment: the Qr code zz and DocumendID would be different. 
books->  DocumendID -> Document()

Comment: the QR code zz is actually the documentID in my example. have a got the documentReference wrong? to get a document I need .collection('collectionName').document('documentID') right?

Comment: I can tell more if you can show Firestore Structure, how you are storing values

Comment: I have just posted it. for reference barcode is equal to b20Us... but it does not find anything. if I put getData('b20Us...') then it finds the document

Comment: Just to be sure, can you add something like `if (barcode == 'b20Us....') print('match'); else print 'no match'; getata(barcode); getata('b20Us....');`

Comment: it printed 'no match' so there was a problem with the barcode scanner. It was adding a space at the end of the string, so the string seemed the same but it was not. thank you all for the help